# Angular HttpClient: Convert HttpResponse to Response

Tags: angular, http, angular5, httpclient, angular-httpclient

While using `Http` we get response type as `Response` from `@angular/http`  library, similarly converting to JSON using `res.json()`

But by using `HttpClient` from  `@angular/common/http` we get direct JSON or `HttpResponse` by using `observe`

Is there any work around to convert type from `Response` to `HttpResponse` or any other way to get response from `HtpClient` so that .json() will work?

Answer (score 0):

http client by default calls res.json() implicitly and you don't need to that manually yourself and set the respond type to `responseType` to `json`

```
JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed
```

[The new Angular HttpClient API](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-new-angular-httpclient-api-9e5c85fe3361)

Comment: yea sir I know that as I mentioned , I cannot go through entire my 750+components/service methods and remove now , so Is  there any altrenative

Comment: @sudhir Did you solve it? I am facing exactly same issue if you any solution please share with. I have also 200+ components app. Searching solution for last 2 days did not get any.