# How to use ionic native http instead of angular http

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic3

Can someone please help me with some code, I'm trying to use ionic native HTTP,
but it is not working. I keep on getting errors when accessing the response from `http.post`. The errors I get are:

> Property 'json' does not exist on type 'HTTPResponse'

or

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise'.

When I use `import { Http } from '@angular/HTTP'` everything works but for some reasons sometimes on the device the `HTTP.post` doesn't work so that's why I want to use `import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';` 
Below I've included both codes, please someone help me.

This works fine:

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {Auth0Config as Config} from '../config/auth0';

@Injectable()
 export class Auth {
 URL: String;

   constructor(public http: Http) {
     this.url = Config.AUTH0_DOMAIN;
   }

   login(user: String, pass: String) {
    let endpoint = "/oauth/token";
    let body = {
        "client_id": Config.AUTH0_CLIENTID,
        "username": user,
        "password": pass,
        "connection": Config.AUTH0_CONNECTION,
        "grant_type": "password"
    };
    return this.http.post(this.url + endpoint, body).map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile(token: String) {
    let endpoint = "/userinfo";
    let query = "?access_token=" + token;
    return this.http.get(this.url + endpoint + query).map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Doesn't work

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {Auth0Config as Config} from '../config/auth0';

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
URL: String;

  constructor(public http: HTTP) {
    this.url = Config.AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  }

  login(user: String, pass: String) {
    let endpoint = "/oauth/token";
    let body = {
        "client_id": Config.AUTH0_CLIENTID,
        "username": user,
        "password": pass,
        "connection": Config.AUTH0_CONNECTION,
        "grant_type": "password"
    };
    return this.http.post(this.url + endpoint, body, {}).then(res => {
        var res = res.json()
    });
  }

  getProfile(token: String) {
    let endpoint = "/userinfo";
    let query = "?access_token=" + token;
    return this.http.get(this.url + endpoint + query, {}, {}) //.map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here :

```
  var res = res.json()
```

The angular http retuns `Promise<Response>`

While the native returns `Promise<HTTPResponse>`

Use this line in its place

```
 var res = res
```

and check this link
[Angular HttpClient: Convert HttpResponse to Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626316/angular-httpclient-convert-httpresponse-to-response)